# Ng1 ui-router and kendo grid $destroy

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

In the AngularJS SPA application I use Kendo grid and application uses the ui-router for routing. On the web site is a hierarchical Kendo grid with 100 rows (server filtering and paging). When I clicked a grid row to go to profile page ui-router waits approx. 6-7s to destroy Kendo grid. It looks like a lot of time. Is it possible to postpone the $destroy event so that the user goes to another page and thereafter $destroy event occurs? Or there is some workaround?

I know this is not a problem because it prevents memory leak, but it looks a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by disabling the filter row in kendo grid. Too many columns and filters in a filter row slow down grid destroy. Grid is first rendered without filter, and then the user can load the grid with the filter if it needs filtering.